# Angular Testing Example Fail

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, browserify, karma-jasmine

Being new to JS unit testing and Angular testing in particular, I tried writing my own tests with Jasmine and Karma. After numerous failed attempts at writing my own tests, I decided to step back and check whether everything is working properly, so I copied the example controller and its tests from the [Angular Documentation on Unit testing](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing) into my project and I am unable to get even that to work.. I feel like a complete idiot that can't even get the copy-pasted code to work..

So here is the controller that I have initialized in the `step1Ctrl.js` file:

Module is initialized in another file.

`var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp");`

```
mainApp.controller('PasswordController', function PasswordController($scope) {   $scope.password = '';   $scope.grade = function() {
    var size = $scope.password.length;
    if (size > 8) {
      $scope.strength = 'strong';
    } else if (size > 3) {
      $scope.strength = 'medium';
    } else {
      $scope.strength = 'weak';
    }   }; });
```

And here's are the tests that live inside `step1Ctrl.spec.js`:

```
describe('PasswordController', function() {
  beforeEach(module('mainApp'));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('$scope.grade', function() {
    var $scope, controller;

    beforeEach(function() {
      $scope = {};
      controller = $controller('PasswordController', { $scope: $scope });
    });

    it('sets the strength to "strong" if the password length is >8 chars', function() {
      $scope.password = 'longerthaneightchars';
      $scope.grade();
      expect($scope.strength).toEqual('strong');
    });

    it('sets the strength to "weak" if the password length <3 chars', function() {
      $scope.password = 'a';
      $scope.grade();
      expect($scope.strength).toEqual('weak');
    });
  });
});
```

Literally copy-pasted from the documentation.

So the error that I get upon running the tests is:

`TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '$controller('PasswordController', { $scope: $scope })')`

Which tells me that the `$controller` function in the second `beforeEach` is failing, as `$controller` is undefined. So it looks like the first `beforeEach` doesn't run, or it does but an undefined value gets injected with the `inject` function.

I am also using `browserify`, if that matters.

Here is my `karma.conf.js`, if that helps, as well:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine'],

    files: [
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js',
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js',
        'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular-mocks.js',
        'test/unit/**/*.js'
    ],

    exclude: [
    ],

    preprocessors: {
        'app/main.js': ['browserify']
    },

    reporters: ['progress'],

    port: 9876,

    colors: true,

    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    autoWatch: true,

    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    browserify: {
        debug: true,
        transform: []
    },

    plugins: [
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher', 'karma-jasmine', 'karma-bro'
    ],

    singleRun: false,


    concurrency: Infinity
    });
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have finally managed to figure out what the problem was. PhantomJS wasn't descriptive with the error messages at all. Apparently, it was failing to instantiate my main Angular module `mainApp`, because I didn't include some source files for external modules that my main module depends on (like `ngAnimate`, etc.).

So I switched my testing browser from `PhantomJS` to Chrome and it actually gave me meaningful errors that quickly pointed in the right direction.

Comment: You are right! Chrome outputs much better information on what failed than PhantomJS does.

Comment: You might want to look at wallabyjs.com to help you, I would not write test without it..

Answer (score 0):

Check whether

- The testing framework is installed, The test conditions belongs to the
  testing framework you are using.
- The "karma.config.js" is configured    for the framework you
  installed.
- Use Browser testing instead of Headless PhantomJS testing to get clear directions.

In most cases above are the errors.